# How to use external JS file in angular6 components

Tags: javascript, angular6

I created an external js file 'countries.js' and included that in angular.json in the scripts array. How can i use that script in a particular component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global var declaration into your js file. ex:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var myJsServices = function() {
   var services = {};
   services.load = function (key) {.....};
   ...
   return services;
}();
</script>
```

And in you Angular service ts file, you declare it just after the imports (outside the class)

```
declare var myJsServices : {
  load : (key) => any,
  ...
};
```

Finally, you can use it like any other angular service.